# changing layout Windows 10

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I want be able to change layout by `left win` on Windows 10. I try to change HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Toggle, but I cant find a solution. Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by Installing auto-hot-key app and creating the `.ahk` script on Desktop with the following lines

```
RWin::
Lwin::
    Send {LShift Down}{LAlt Down}{LShift Up}{LAlt Up}
return
```

after that you should only run this script by double clicking (or press Enter)